# iText7 flips text - bug?

Tags: itext7

Consider a 1-page PDF document named `in.pdf` that looks like this:

[image]

We execute the following code in C#:

```cs
using (var reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\<path>\in.pdf"))
using (var writer = new PdfWriter(@"C:\<path>\out.pdf"))
using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
{
    var page = pdfDoc.GetFirstPage();
    var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);

    using (var canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, new Rectangle(400, 300)))
    {
        canvas.Add(new Paragraph("new text\r\nnew text")
            .SetFontColor(new DeviceRgb(255, 0, 0))
            .SetFontSize(50));
    }

    pdfCanvas.Release();
}
```

We get new text appearing under the original text, as expected:

[image]

Now we execute the same code with one change - we create `PdfCanvas` as follows:

```cs
var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
```

Result is still as expected - new text is above the original text:

[image]

Finally, we execute the same code with `PdfCanvas` created as follows:

```cs
var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamAfter(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
```

New text is above the original text as expected, but it's flipped!

[image]

Is this a bug? Getting the same flipped output creating `PdfCanvas` like this:

```cs
var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.GetFirstContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
//OR
var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.GetLastContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
```

Using nuget package `itext7 v7.1.15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is this a bug?*

*No. It's matching your code and a feature of the `PdfCanvas(PdfPage page)` constructor.*

Each PDF content stream contains a sequence of instructions that change the current graphics state and/or draw something. If the original creator of the respective content stream did not take care to clean up the graphics state, instructions you add to it or to a following content stream of the same page are subject to those graphics state changes.

In your case the original page content stream apparently at the end has a graphics state with the current transformation matrix set to a reflection. Depending on how you add your new content, your additions also are subject to that reflection transformation:

- ```
  var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
  ```

  Here you add a new content stream *before* all existing content streams. Thus, your additions to `pdfCanvas` are not subject to any graphics state changes and you get upright text.
- ```
  var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
  ```

  The constructor you use here, `PdfCanvas(PdfPage page)`, calls another constructor, `PdfCanvas(PdfPage page, bool wrapOldContent)`, which for `wrapOldContent == true` wraps the existing content in an envelope of a **save-graphics-state** / **restore-graphics-state** instruction pair, to restore the original graphics state after the existing content. `PdfCanvas(PdfPage page)` uses a `true` value for `wrapOldContent` under certain conditions, in particular if you are manipulating an existing PDF and the page in question already has a non-empty content stream.

  In your case, therefore, the original content is wrapped in such an envelope and the graphics state is restored thereafter. So your additions are not subject to any graphics state changes and you get upright text.
- ```
  var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamAfter(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);

  var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.GetFirstContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);

  var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.GetLastContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
  ```

  The `PdfCanvas` constructors you use here do not add any such envelope. Thus, your additions are subject to graphics state changes in the original content and you get mirrored text.

Comment: **mkl** thank you very much for the detailed reply. I created original document in `MS Word` and then printed to PDF using `Microsoft Print to PDF` printer. I have now tried to print the same doc to PDF using `Adobe PDF` printer, and do not get flipped output anymore. Looks like the MS printer does not do as good a job cleaning up after itself.

Comment: Well, strictly said it is not required to clean up, merely good style... ;)